# Expression to convert IQueryable<t> int List<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I would like to create a repository method like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> AllAsSelectListItems(
    Expression<Func<T, string>> valueProperty, 
    Expression<Func<T, string>> textProperty, 
    string selectedValue = "")
{
    // what goes here? I am having serious trouble with this bit!
}
```

That will enable me to call it like this:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = PersonRepository.AllAsSelectListItems(
    m => m.ID,
    m => m.Name,
    selectedIDAsString
);
```

And, with the `selectedValue` parameter being "1", it should produce a result like this:

```
List<SelectListItem>(){
    {Value: "1", Text: "Ted", Selected: true},
    {Value: "2", Text: "Sam", Selected: false},
    {Value: "3", Text: "Tracy", Selected: false}
};
```

I am having trouble with the generic `AllAsSelectListItems()` method.

You can see my attempt so far in the code below.  But it's not ideal.

I have resorted to hard-coded strings to populate `SelectListItem` properties with `T` properties. I think an expression tree is the solution, but I'm struggling to code it correctly.

Also, assigning the `ID` property breaks it, because it's an `int` not a `string`.

Finally, I am also struggling to compare the `selectedValue` parameter to the `SelectListItem.Value` property.

---

**Person Class**

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class PersonController : Controller 
{
    public IPersonRepository Repository {get;set;}

    public PersonController(IPersonRepository repository) 
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult SelectPerson(int selectedID)
    {
        string selectedIDAsString = selectedID.ToString();
        var selectListItems = Repository.AllAsSelectListItems(
            m => m.ID,
            m => m.Name,
            selectedIDAsString
        );
        return View(selectListItems);
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class PersonRepository : Repository
{
     // various specialised methods 
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : DBEntity
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = null;
    private DbSet<T> table = null;

    public RepositoryBase()
    {
        this.db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }
    public RepositoryBase(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<T> AllAsQueryable(
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
    {
        return includeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
            (table, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> AllAsSelectListItems(
        Expression<Func<T, string>> valueProperty, 
        Expression<Func<T, string>> textProperty, 
        string selectedValue = "")
    {
        // temp hard coded values until we learn how to use the expression parameters properly
        string valuePropertyHardCoded = "Name";
        string textPropertyHardCoded = "Name";
        Type currentType = typeof(T);
        var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(currentType, "x");
        var valueMember = Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, valuePropertyHardCoded);
        var textMember = Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, textPropertyHardCoded);

        var selector = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(SelectListItem)),
            Expression.Bind(typeof(SelectListItem).GetMember("Value").Single(), valueMember),
            Expression.Bind(typeof(SelectListItem).GetMember("Text").Single(), textMember)
        );
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, SelectListItem>>(
            selector, itemParam);

        return AllAsQueryable().Select(lambda.Compile()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm a bit confused, _AllAsSelectListItemsSpecifyProperties_ is how you try write _AllAsSelectListItems_? or this some other method that work ok?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo from copy and paste.  Thanks for pointing it out. It should have been `AllAsSelectListItems()`. Now updated.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `string selectedValue = ""` argument?

Comment: To compare against each `SelectListItem.Value`.  If they're the same, we mark `SelectListItem.Selected` as `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. There are few things to be realized:

(A) Binding the passed `valueProperty` and `textProperty` expressions to a common parameter. Since the assumption is that they represent a property/field accessor, the passed expression `Body` should be of type `MemberExpression` and the actual member info can be extracted from `MemberExpression.Member` property.

(B) Generating the `Selected` assignment by using `Expression.Equal`

Putting it all together, it will look something like this

```
public List<SelectListItem> AllAsSelectListItems(
        Expression<Func<T, string>> valueProperty,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> textProperty,
        string selectedValue = "")
{
    if (valueProperty == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueProperty");
    if (textProperty == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("textProperty");
    if (!(valueProperty.Body is MemberExpression)) throw new ArgumentException("Must be a field or property.", "valueProperty");
    if (!(textProperty.Body is MemberExpression)) throw new ArgumentException("Must be a field or property.", "textProperty");
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var valueMember = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(item, ((MemberExpression)valueProperty.Body).Member);
    var textMember = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(item, ((MemberExpression)textProperty.Body).Member);
    var targetType = typeof(SelectListItem);
    var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>
    {
        Expression.Bind(targetType.GetProperty("Value"), valueMember),
        Expression.Bind(targetType.GetProperty("Text"), textMember)
    };
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
        bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(targetType.GetProperty("Selected"), Expression.Equal(valueMember, Expression.Constant(selectedValue))));
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, SelectListItem>>(
        Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(targetType), bindings), item);
    var query = AllAsQueryable().Select(selector);
    var result = query.ToList();
    return result;
}
```

**Update:** Unfortunately `SelectListItem.Value` is of type `string`, and most of the time the source property (usually some sort of Id) is not a `string`. So let rename `valueProperty` to `valueSelector` and allow passing something like `x => x.Id.ToString()`. While we cannot easily rebind the passed expression, but we can easily use it unchanged and instead of creating a new parameter, just reuse the parameter of that expression.

The modified method now would be something like this

```
public List<SelectListItem> AllAsSelectListItems(
        Expression<Func<T, string>> valueSelector,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> textProperty,
        string selectedValue = "")
{
    if (valueSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");
    if (textProperty == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("textProperty");
    if (!(textProperty.Body is MemberExpression)) throw new ArgumentException("Must be a field or property.", "textProperty");
    var item = valueSelector.Parameters[0];
    var itemValue = valueSelector.Body;
    var itemText = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(item, ((MemberExpression)textProperty.Body).Member);
    var targetType = typeof(SelectListItem);
    var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>
    {
        Expression.Bind(targetType.GetProperty("Value"), itemValue),
        Expression.Bind(targetType.GetProperty("Text"), itemText)
    };
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
        bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(targetType.GetProperty("Selected"), Expression.Equal(itemValue, Expression.Constant(selectedValue))));
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, SelectListItem>>(Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(targetType), bindings), item);
    var query = AllAsQueryable().Select(selector);
    var result = query.ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It makes sense now I see it, and with your explanations, but I would NEVER have been able to come up with that myself

Comment: If I want to pass in an `int` property as the `valueProperty` parameter, how might I go about doing that?  I tried to create overloads with `Expression<Func<T, int>>` and `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, but I don't understand how to edit the bindings section.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Let me think a little. The problem is that it needs to be converted to `string` I guess?

Comment: I think so.   I am trying various ways, but I am not really sure where in the code I should attempt to put the conversion.

Comment: If it's a pain, I can ask as a separate question.  I am delighted just to have it working on strings right now :)

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Np mate, I've updated the answer to handle `ToString` expression, hope that helps.